# Changing a sql query using join instead of a subselect

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

i've got the following problem:
Because the amount of entries could get very big, I would like to use a join instead of a subselect in a sql query.

It regards the following three simplified tables:

```
devices:
- id

confirmation_requests:
- id
- filePath

confirmation
- id
- requestId (references confirmation_requests.id)
- deviceId (references devices.id)
```

The target is, to get all confirmation requests, which are not confirmed (with an entry in the confirmation table) by a given device.

I just come to a solution using an ordinary subquery, an example you find here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13fd3/1

```
SELECT * 
FROM confirmation_requests 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT confirmation_request_id
                     FROM confirmations
                     WHERE device_id = 1);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `LEFT JOIN` onto the table for confirmations matching `device_id = 1` then exclude those in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT cr.* 
FROM confirmation_requests cr
LEFT JOIN confirmations c ON (cr.id = c.confirmation_request_id AND c.device_id = 1)
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Any idea how to implement it with Propel? I tried it with: `$confirmationRequests = ConfirmationRequestQuery::create()
      ->leftJoin("Confirmation c")
       ->addJoinCondition("c","c.device_id = ?",$device->getId())
      ->where("c.id IS NULL")
      ->find();`

Comment: @user2362649 Propel isn't something I've used before. You may have more luck asking that as a new question.

Comment: Mh .. maybe it doesn't work as I thought.. Let's say I've got 2 devices (id: 1 and 2) ... and there are only 2 confirmation_requests for device-1 but no entries in the confirmation table... The query should output those two requests for the first device... That is working so far...But if I call this for second device I also get this two requests. Normally nothing should come out, because those two requests belong to the first device..

Comment: @user2362649 This isn't the behaviour I see using your SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13fd3/13 could you create a fiddle showing the issue?